# parse api request to horeku mongodb returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: mongodb, parsing, heroku, react-native

I am building react native mobile app and a backend service I am using parse service, as many of you know Parse service is shutting down in 2017 and I have migrated my data to mlab(mongo db). I am using  Heroku for application platform.

Now when I am making rest api request from my app or rest api tool i.e. Postman then I am keep getting :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
        <title>Application Error</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
            <p>Application Error</p>

        </iframe>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Here is my request with header:

Header: X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/Message/KwSKveyh9C

What am I doing wrong ?

[Parse REST API request failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNPHp.png)

Comment: did you solve it?